# Laravel 5.5 - laravel/socialite scopes and redirect

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Can somebody explain to me what are scopes in laravel/socialite and how can I define multiple redirect from services.php

I need one for sign up with facebook, and another for login with facebook

config/services.php

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => '***************',
        'client_secret' => '****************',
        'redirectForSignUp' => 'http://localhost:8000/register/facebook/callback',
        'redirectForLogin' => 'http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback',
 ],
```

Comment: Scopes are the various Facebook data permissions listed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/. You can't (easily) have multiple redirects, to my knowledge - store something in the session and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this is:

```
public function redirectToProvider($accountType, $provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)
        ->with(['redirect_uri' => "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/{$accountType}/{$provider}/callback/"])
        ->redirect();
}
```

You could use this method to replace anything in the http request url (including scopes).

To override other things like scopes, simply:

```
->with([scopes => 'SCOPES HERE', redirect_url => ''])
->redirect();
```

Answer (score -2):

Open your .env file and set following value in it bottom

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxx
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxx
CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback
```

Then after opwn **config/services.php** file and set following value

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL'),
],
```

Visit thiss link for full **laravel/socialite** configuration in laravel application

http://laravelcode.com/post/laravel54-login-with-facebook-in-laravel